Do any Poskim still respond with full teshuvos/responsa?

It seems like until recently, it wasn't very hard to get a comprehensive teshuva to a shaila one had. Sefarim like Igros Moshe, Shevet Haleivi, Minchas Yitzchak, Tzitz Eliezer etc. are compilations of questions sent to the Posek, with comprehensive answers detailing the methodology and reasoning behind the psak.
I often have halachic questions that are more complex than a regular CYLOR shaila, which I would love to pose to a bona-fide posek and receive not just a psak, but a responsum to validate the psak.
Which contemporary Rabbanim accept shailas (by email or regular mail) and will reply, and how do I contact them?

(This question and this question are looking for Rabbis who will issue a ruling. I am looking for Rabbis - ideally of 'Posek' stature - who will write responsa.)

I know that R' Moshe Shternbuch and R' Asher Weiss both have written responsa, and I presume still do. Does anyone know how to submit a shaila to either posek?

Rabbi Michael Avraham has a lot of his shutim that he posts online https://mikyab.net/שות/

No one has time to respond with full length responsa to every random person who emails a question. (In other words, with email accessibility, the number of questions goes up and the average quality goes down.) Even if you find rabbis who do this, you also need to find a way to convince them your question is worth their time.

"and how do I contact them".. I understand your desire to solicit this information, but would caution those sharing such information to consider whether the respective poseq would in fact want their contact information made publicly available in this way and/or on this forum

R Asher Weiss has a website and contact information but I strongly doubt he would respond to anything but a community-relevant question. He has an entire kollel of dayanim answering questions

My friend asked Rav Asher Weiss a question in person and Rav Asher liked the question so much he wrote a whole teshuva on it, and put it in his Teshuvos Minchas Asher

"It wasn't very hard" is not true. The people you listed only published a small fraction of their pesakim. Rav Moshe would pasken dozens, if not hundreds of questions every day. I believe most of the published ones were written specifically to rabbis who were qualified poskim in their own right who had particularly complex questions, or presented detailed arguments he needed to respond to.

Rabbi David Golinkin responds to halacha questions with full, detailed responses.
Contact info and record of his responsa can be found here
https://schechter.edu/responsa-by-david-golinkin/
Not an individual posek, but the Beit Din of America often provides responsa-esque write ups of their halachic decisions (source) and can be reached here
